# How to change the environment of non-exported functions?

Tags: r, namespaces, package

Is there a way, to change the execution environment of a non-exported function defined in package's namespace?

My goal is to swiftly force this function to follow different scoping path to invoke some custom methods/objects (defined in the new environment), without the need of duplicating the whole package.
Currently, I'm unsuccessful with

```
> environment(ggplot2:::create_layout)
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
> env <- new.env()
> parent.env(env) <- asNamespace('ggplot2')
> environment(ggplot2:::create_layout) <- new.env
Error in environment(ggplot2:::create_layout) <- new.env : 
  object 'ggplot2' not found
```

In this specific example i would like `create_layout` to use a modified version of `ggplot2`'s `ggproto` function and `Layer` object present in the `env` environment. My logic was that changing the searching scope is less messy, than modifying the object's body inside the namespace.

Comment: Package environments are generally locked so you can't reassign a new value to an existing symbol in a namespace (which is what happens when you try to change a functions environment). Can you give a more specific example of a behavior you are trying to change?

Comment: I guess it's just a duplicate of other questions concerning `assignInNamespace`, since the solution can be achieved with creating a local copy of `create_layout`, changing it's environment with `environment<-`, and then calling `assignInNamespace('create_layout', create_layout, ns = 'ggplot2')`.
I've also edited my post with description of what I want to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388570/how-to-modify-unexported-object-in-a-package